# To calculate shift in the shifted lognormal model

Tags: interest-rates

I tried to calculate the shift for CHF interest rates (tenors with negative rates) using MLE, but as the shift is increased the MLE value increases(or decreases depending on whether positive or negative shift used) and hence doesn't converge to any particular value. 
So I wanted to know if there are any other definite ways of calculating shift in the Shifted lognormal approach for Negative Interest Rates.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following, but one thought: you are taking the log of (1+i) where i is the interest rate as a fraction (.05 = 5%), correct?